# Change the div position on desktop

Tags: html, css

I have these 2 divs (`footer-txt` and `footer-img`), on the mobile it works perfectly because I want the text on top and the 2 images on the bottom, like side by side.

But when the screen gets wider, I want the 2 images side by side and also the text div. Like a row with the 2 images and the text.

Is there a way that I can do this?

```css
#footer {
  background-color: #98AFFF;
}

.footer-txt {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #464646;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer-img {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start" id="footer">

  <div class="p-4" id="footer-content">

    <div class="pb-2 footer-txt">
      PROTESTE
    </div>

    <div class="pt-4 pb-2 justify-content-center footer-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group (1).png" alt="Google">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group.png" alt="Google">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: I made a snippet and removed the loose `</div>` you had

Comment: Look into flex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand correctly you can put this css in id `#footer-content`:

```
#footer-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

That way you change the direction of your `div` to as if it were a row.

If you only need this for when you're not mobile, you can add the following line:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
   #footer-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired solution can be achieved using either `Flex-Box` or `Grid` & Responsive CSS using `Media Queries`

- [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)
- [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
- [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

```css
#footer {
  background-color: #98AFFF;
}

#footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 25px;
}

.footer-txt {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #464646;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer-img {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
}

/* Styling for Smaller Screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #footer-content {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start" id="footer">
  <div class="p-4" id="footer-content">
    <div class="pb-2 footer-txt">
      PROTESTE
    </div>
    <div class="pt-4 pb-2 justify-content-center footer-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group (1).png" alt="Google">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group.png" alt="Google">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the text and both of the images a flex item. You achive this by defining the flex property on the footer-content. All of its direct children are then flex-items.

Very good explanation of flex can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If my solution is not what are you looking for you are maybe also looking for breakpoints and media queries for a responsive design.

```css
#footer {
    background-color: #98AFFF;
}

.footer-txt {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #464646;
    text-align: left;
}

#footer-content {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-content">
    <div class="footer-txt">
      PROTESTE
    </div>
    <div class="footer-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group (1).png" alt="Google">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/pag1/Mask group.png" alt="Google">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```